# Clang equivalent to msvc pragma function()

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, clang, llvm

I'm currently compiling and running my C99 code for windows using Microsoft's latest visual c compiler. I'm also not linking to any standard c libraries. In order to do so I have to define a couple c library functions which are used by the compiler (apparently). In order to do so I'm defining them like so:

```
#pragma function(memset)
void* memset(void* dest, int c, size_t count)
{
    char* bytes = (char*)dest;
    while(count--)
    {
        *bytes++ = (char)c;
    }

    return dest;
}

#pragma function(memcpy)
void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t count)
{
    char* dest8 = (char*)dest;
    const char* src8 = (const char*)src;
    while(count--)
    {
        *dest8++ = *src8++;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

I'm wondering what the equivalent of the `#pragma function()` would be in clang/llvm compiler toolset? I'm having trouble finding it within the docs and the compiler is complaining about memset being undefined currently.

Edit:

Here is a minimal compilable example which will run into the error I'm currently experiencing:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//This is normally a part of the c runtime library so have to define it here
int _fltused = 0x9875;

//#define invalid_code_path __debugbreak()

void error_func()
{
    //msvc break
    //__debugbreak();
}

#define BGZ_ASSERT(condition) \
do { \
    if(!(condition)) \
        error_func(); \
} while (0)  

bool app_running = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK win32_program_window_callback(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    LRESULT result = { 0 };

    //For hardware rendering
    HDC WindowContext = GetDC(WindowHandle);
    
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: {
        }break;
        
        case WM_PAINT: {
            //To understand why you need a display buffer call here as well as game loop, see this post:
            //https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/825-wm_paint_question_beginner
            PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
            HDC deviceContext = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &Paint);

            EndPaint(WindowHandle, &Paint);
        } break;
        
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            app_running = false;
        } break;
        
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            app_running = false;
        } break;
        
        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP: {
        } break;
        
        default: {
            result = DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam, lParam);
        } break;
    }
    
    return result;
};

void win32_process_pending_messages(HWND window) {
    MSG message;
    while(PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        switch(message.message) {
            case WM_QUIT: {
                app_running = false;
            }break;

            case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_KEYUP: {

            }break;

            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL: {
                int delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(message.wParam);
            }break;

            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            case WM_LBUTTONUP: {

            }break;

            default: {
                TranslateMessage(&message);
                DispatchMessageA(&message);
            }break;
        }
    }
}

void __stdcall WinMainCRTStartup() {
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    
    WNDCLASS window_properties = {0};
    window_properties.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //TODO: Check if OWNDC/HREDRAW/VEDRAW matter
    window_properties.lpfnWndProc = win32_program_window_callback;
    window_properties.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    window_properties.lpszClassName = "my_window_class";
    window_properties.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    if(RegisterClass(&window_properties)) {
        DWORD window_styles = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        RECT rect = (RECT){ 0, 0, (LONG)1280, (LONG)720 };
        BOOL success = AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, window_styles, false, 0);

        HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0, window_properties.lpszClassName, "My Window", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 0, 0, window_properties.hInstance, 0);
        HDC window_context = GetDC(window);

        if(window && window_context) {
            app_running = true; 

            while(app_running) {
                win32_process_pending_messages(window);
            }

            PostMessage(window, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    ExitProcess(result);
}
```

and the build file using clang-cl link-lld:

```
@echo off

REM This represents the full directory path to your batch file
set cwd=%~dp0

REM My own thing. Equivalent to vcvarsall.bat
call "C:\msvc\setup.bat"

REM I believe above "call 'C:msvc\..." changes directorys so making sure to change back to current directory
cd /d %cwd%

REM -GS- tells compiler to not worry about security calls (like __security_cookie) that would typically be inserted with c libs. -Gs99999999999 basically says don't worry about __chkdsk for checking stack overruns
set compiler_flags=-Z7 -nologo -Oi -Od -Ob1 -WX -W4 -GR -EHa- -GS- -Gs999999999 -wd4505 -wd4101 -wd4530 -w14700 -wd4100 -we4820 -wd4201 -wd4189
REM -STACK:0x100000,0x100000 is setting function stack default to 1MB. Can increase this if we need to. Keep in mind though this also increases default stack size for all threads created
set linker_flags=-subsystem:windows -machine:x64 -incremental:no -nologo -opt:ref -debug -ignore:4099 -NODEFAULTLIB -STACK:0x100000,0x100000

set include_paths=-I"%cwd%source" -I"C:\msvc\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um"
set library_paths=-LIBPATH:"C:\msvc\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64"
set import_libraries="kernel32.lib" "user32.lib"

IF NOT EXIST bin mkdir bin
pushd bin

clang-cl /c ..\source\editor\editor.c %compiler_flags% 
lld-link editor.obj -dll %linker_flags%

clang-cl /c ..\source\*.c %compiler_flags% %include_paths% -DBGZ_WIN64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
lld-link *.obj -OUT:win64_main.exe %linker_flags% %library_paths% %import_libraries%

popd
```

Comment: Try `-fno-builtin`.

Comment: Would you mind to add a [mre] for Clang, completely with commands to compile and link, please? -- What is the purpose of `#pragma function(x)`, in addition to the definition of a function?

Comment: I believe just lets you override a compiler intrinsic function and with msvc it uses memset and memcpy internally. So since I'm not linking to the c library I have to define these myself and tell the compiler to use my defines instead

Comment: Also tried adding -fno-builtin to the command line but same error.

Comment: You could try `-fno-builtin -ffreestanding`.

Comment: It just says it doesn't recognize the argument. After a quick search it looks like -ffreestanding is a GCC compiler argument. Also, I think I need a way to actually implement the memset call like I do for the msvc compiler so I need some kind of #pragma equivalent to implement in my code

Comment: No, you don't need anything like that. You need `-fno-builtin`. Nothing more, nothing less.